# C how to cut down on if statements

Tags: c

I am relatively new to the programming scene. I have tried a few languages but settled on C to start with because of the support and ease of getting started. I am currently trying to write a simple text based conquest kind of game.
 With this there are a large amount of places or territory to choose to attack and what not. I gave each territory a numerical ID 1-50 here's where my problem is. The only way I can think of to test which ID the user has entered is to write 50 if statements which is super tedious and annoying. Is there an easier way of doing this?

```
  AttackTrue(){
int AmountOfTroops;
int TerrToAttack;
//List of territories with their id 
// example: int California = 1;
    printf("You have %d troops\n"); 
    printf("Enter the number of troops you want to use.");
            scanf(" %d",&AmountOfInfantry);
            printf("Enter the ID of the territory you want to attack.\n");
            scanf(" %d",&TerrToAttack);
            /*HERE IS WHERE ALL THE IF STATEMENTS WOULD GO*/
            }

}
```

Comment: What about `strtol()` or `atoi()`?

Comment: Post a snippet of what you have (use [edit] to add it). As it is, all I can say is "probably".

Comment: It depends on how you've structured it, as @Jongware mentioned. For example, if you're using a `struct` to represent a `territory`, and you have an array of `territory`s, then you can simply index into the array and call `attack(territories[user_input])`

Answer (score 1):

You can use switch case as JerryGoyal suggested.
Another aproach will be to use an array of pointers to functions:

```
void* (*funcLUT[50])(void*);
```

create an init function to populate the array (it's good to have a DoNothing() function as default value) and call the function according to the ID:

```
retValue = funcLUT[ID](data);
```

Hope I helped

Comment: Barebones answer, but something that the OP could implement in seconds, thus +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

use [`switch`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/switch_statement_in_c.htm) case instead of `if else`.

```
  scanf("%d",&a);    
    switch ( a ) {
    case 1:
      /* Code */
      break;
    case 2:
      /* Code */
      break;
.
.
.
    default:
      /* Code */
      break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Switch](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/switch_statement_in_c.htm) or [Ternary Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). It is on implementation specific what to use. You will get good run time performance case of `Switch` over `if-else`

Comment: I think a ternary for 50 cases would be way worse than `if-else`s ;)

Comment: @szczurcio: Actually code snippet will give more information about what is in conditional statement so that we can suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You're learning how to program. The main issues come not from the language itself, but rather from how you **engineer** your system. Let me propose to you that you're not asking the right question.

What you have right now is a poor understanding of your problem. It is not advisable to somehow force code to "better" fit that poor understand. Just try to rethink the problem.

For example, how about seeing your territory as a grid. Specifically, a two-dimensional grid. Then go on and populate that grid with cells.

```
typedef struct Cell {void (*cellBehaviour)(struct Cell *);} Cell;
typedef struct Grid {Cell *cells;} Grid;
```

From here, you can attach different behaviour to each cell (or they can have default behaviour, it's up to you). Behaviour is expressed using functions, so you could have something like this.

```
void cellBehaviourDefault(struct Cell *cell);
```

Assign some behaviour function to each cell and then you don't need **any** if's, just whenever you have a cell to do something with, call it's behaviour function.

```
cell.cellBehaviour(cell);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in passing in the comments, you could perhaps structure your `territories` to model the following:

```
struct territory
{
    // territory code...

};
```

Since you mentioned you have 50 `territories`, this can be solved quite nicely by creating an array of `territories` and simply calling a function with the appropriate `territory` as an argument. This way, there's no need to use a long chain of if/else statements. Here's an example:

```
void attack(struct territory* to_attack)
{
    // attack the territory
}

int main()
{
    const int num_territories = 50;
    struct territory territories[num_territories];   
    int territory_id;

    // code logic, call the following in a loop perhaps, based on user input:
    scanf("%i",&territory_id);
    attack(&territories[territory_id]);
}
```

I passed the `territory` by pointer so that any changes you make to it in the `attack` function actually get reflected throughout the game. If any territories need special treatment or should be attacked differently, a simple flag within the `territory` struct should be enough for you to implement this change in the `attack` function. And, in case you ever grow your territories to more than 50, there's only a single variable to change (`num_territories`), as opposed to adding new blocks of `if/else` logic.